# Is it possible to use Devtools' Sass support with Scout?

Tags: sass, rubygems, google-chrome-devtools, compass-sass, scout-sass

I'm using [Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) as SASS compiler. I would like to know if there's a way to configure Scout to work with DevTools Sass support.(Auto reload css upon save). I assume installing Scout should install Compass and SASS in my machine. When I tried 'compass' in the terminal, I get 'compass: command not found'.

Do I have to install sass separately for this to work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As long as you have a compiler that can run in the watch mode (akin to `sass --watch my.scss:my.css`, i.e. recompile your css'en based on changes in your sass, scss, whatever files), you should be good to go. Please refer to the Scout documentation to see how this mode can be activated.

Comment: @Natasha, I'll look into this. I'm currently writing ScoutApp version 2 for release later this summer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response guys. It seems like the version of SASS ScoutApp is using doesnt have source map support. According to this [article](http://benfrain.com/add-sass-compass-debug-info-for-chrome-web-developer-tools/), you need Sass 3.3.